# Ajax returns 404 error in Laravel 8 but the route exists

Tags: jquery, laravel, routes, jquery-select2

I am implementing JQuery Select2() in my form. When I try to search, my ajax always returns 404 error. But the route exists in the web.php file.

Here is my code:

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/searchByName/{var1}', [App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentsController::class, 'searchByName'])->name('searchByName');
```

**JS File**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    url = $(".js-example-basic-single").attr('data-url');
    $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
        dropdownParent: $('.name-search-box'),
        language: {
            inputTooShort: function () {return "Plase enter minimum 3 caracteres";},
            minimumInputLength: function () {return "Plase enter minimum 3 caracteres";},
            noResults: function () {return "no results";}
        },
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        placeholder: "Select a patient",
        allowClear: true,
        width: "100%",
        debug: true,
        ajax: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/searchByName",
            delay: 500,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
            var query = {
                search: params.term
            }

            // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&type=public
            return query;
            },
            processResults: function (resp) { console.log('response' + resp);
                return {
                    results: resp
                }
            },
            cache: true
        }

    });

}
```

**AppointmentsController.php**

```
public function searchByName($var1){
    
        $key = $request->get('search');
        $name = DB::table('patients_tbl')->select('id', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name')
                ->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$key%")->get()->toArray();
        
        return $name;
    
}
```

I have tried route with and without parameters, cleared all types of cache including route cache etc but no use.

Comment: Your url is url: "/searchByName", but your route is '/searchByName/{var1}' you need to add your url to variable.

Answer (score 1):

The route in your ajax file doesn't provide parameter.
In url: "/searchByName" but in routes it has one parameter as {var1}

```
ajax: {
   type: "GET",
   url: "/searchByName",
   delay: 500,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: function (params) {
   var query = {
       search: params.term
}
```

Try this code once:

```
var uri = "{{ route('searchByName', ':variable') }}";
uri = uri.replace(':variable', var1);
$.ajax({
   url: uri,
   type: 'get',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your js is fetch url like

```
localhost/searchByName?search=abc
```

but route in php is defined is

```
localhost/searchByName/abc
```

It is diffirent .

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing method from `GET` to `POST` and adding `_token` with parameter in ajax function. Here is my corrected code

**JS File**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //var uri = "{{ route('searchByName', ':variable') }}";
    //uri = uri.replace(':variable', var1);
    //alert(uri);
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
        dropdownParent: $('.name-search-box'),
        language: {
            inputTooShort: function () {return "Plase enter minimum 3 caracteres";},
            //minimumInputLength: function () {return "Plase enter minimum 3 caracteres";},
            noResults: function () {return "no results";}
        },
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        placeholder: "Select a patient",
        allowClear: true,
        width: "100%",
        debug: true,
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            url: '/searchByName',
            delay: 500,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
            return {
                _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                search: params.term // search term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) { console.log(data);
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                        return { id: obj.id, text: obj.first_name };
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }

    });

});
```

and **web.php**

```
Route::post('/searchByName', [App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentsController::class, 'searchByName'])->name('searchByName');
```